# Open Stack endpoints API request OS X

Tags: python, linux, bash, openstack

I've got the following bash script to parse endpoints JSON:

```
echo curl  -s -H "X-Auth-Token: my_access_token" -X GET "https://api.selvpc.ru/identity/v3/endpoints?interface=public" | python -mjson.tool | grep -Pi '^\s*"url":\s*".*",?$' | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d '"' | sed "s/[%\\\$](tenant_id)s/my_project_id/g")
```

But bash says:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `)'

My hoster says, this script works well on Linux-based OS, but no guarantee to work on OS X. What can be the syntax issue?

**EDIT:**

If i use the following:

```
curl  -s -H "X-Auth-Token: my_access_token" -X GET "https://api.selvpc.ru/identity/v3/endpoints?interface=public" | python -mjson.tool
```

JSON parses as expected. But with `grep -Pi '^\s*"url":\s*".*",?$'` I guess it causes `grep` warning

> usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
>       [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
>       [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
>       [--null] [pattern] [file ...]

I guess the first problem is grep error?

Comment: Well, there's clearly a trailing `)` at the end of this pipeline. Flagging for closure because this is a typographic error.

Comment: @4ae1e1 yep, got it. Now it's :

usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
 [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
 [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
No JSON object could be decoded

Comment: Okay. First, if you want to run `curl`, then why do you write an `echo` in front? Remove that `echo`. Secondly, from your `grep` synopsis it appears that your `grep` doesn't support `-P`; are you on OS X by any chance? (Ah yes, now I see the sentence about OS X.) In that case you need to modify the regex a bit (escaping `?` is enough, actually): `grep -i '^\s*"url":\s*".*",\?$'`.

Comment: But seriously, parsing JSON with `grep` and `awk`, `tr`, `sed` etc. is bad. Get a dedicated JSON processor, e.g., [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: yep, @4ae1e1, escaping ? helped and removing -P) Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, "escaping" is the wrong word here... In any case I mean replace `?` by `\?`, because we're dealing with BRE here, where `?` is a literal question mark, and `\?` is the magical metacharacter.

Answer (score 0):

As @4ae1e1 suggested, please use a JSON processor for the job. jq is great and it's worthwhile investing your time to learn it.

```
wget https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/download/jq-1.5/jq-osx-amd64
mv jq-osx-amd64 jq
chmod u+x jq

curl -s -H "X-Auth-Token: $TOKEN" https://api.selvpc.ru/identity/v3/endpoints?interface=public | \
  ./jq -r .endpoints[].url
```

That will get you a list of OpenStack API endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I think a python script using python-keystoneclient can be easier to understand and maintain